# How to fix black screen while trying to connect again in Kurento room on iOS?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, webrtc, videochat, kurento

I'm using Kurento room on iOS https://github.com/nubomediaTI/Kurento-iOS and found that random bug with black screen sometimes appears when I'm trying to reconnect to the same room. I have sound while connected, but have no video, only black screen. After 40-50 seconds the video appears. Don't find any issues in my logs but found the same bug with Kurento on other platforms.

Comment: I don't know Kurento, does it automatically renegotiate SDPs? You usually need to generate a new offer and answer when reconnecting to a room.

Comment: @Kevin check this out, please http://builds.kurento.org/dev/master/latest/kurento-room-docs/websocket_api_room_server.html#unsubscribe-from-video : when I left room I send unsubscribeFromVideo request but don't receive SDP answer like it's said in doc. I receive ```Error Domain=org.kurento.Room Code=803 "Invalid method lacking parameter sdpAnswer"``` After I've already left room with this error, I'm trying to recconnect and sometimes it fails with this black screen.